# scrollbar not changing on class change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a small scrollbar as default and when the scrollbar gets hovered it should get normal size.

This works great except that when only the scrollbar-track is hovered only the track extends and the thumb remains at half size.

I tried selectors like + ~ to change the thumb-size while the track is hovered, but they don't work here, so I tried my luck with JavaScript.

I added a class to the body every time the cursor gets near the scrollbar and removed it if the cursor is more than 5px away.
Because that didn't work I also added a class for the opposite, but while the classes are changing correctly, the style gets only updated when you hover the scrollbar, which makes it impossible to change.

Here is the code (I edited it a bit, so you can see the problem best, even in jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/timlg07/k697nxdv/

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  if (evt.clientX >= (document.body.clientWidth - 5)) {
    document.body.classList.add("scrollbar-hover");
    document.body.classList.remove("scrollbar-normal");
  } else if (document.body.classList.contains("scrollbar-hover")) {
    document.body.classList.remove("scrollbar-hover");
    document.body.classList.add("scrollbar-normal");
  }
});
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: transparent;
  width: 16px;
}

body.scrollbar-normal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

body.scrollbar-hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}


/* THUMB: */

body.scrollbar-normal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 2%;
  /* background simulating half width (width can't be changed onhover) + hover-trigger gets bigger */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 0%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 50%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 51%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 95%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 96%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 0%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 50%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 51%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 95%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 96%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 0%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 50%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 51%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 1) 95%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 96%, rgba(188, 188, 188, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00bcbcbc', endColorstr='#00bcbcbc', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9*/
}

body.scrollbar-hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<body class="scrollbar-normal" style="background:#333">

  <div style="height:300vh;width:70vw;margin:auto;background:#aaa">sample content</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This bug is fixed in chromium now. 
Example: https://github.com/timlg07/Fluent-Design/tree/master/scrollbar